# Evaluating the integral $\int \frac{x-1}{(x+1) \sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The integral to be evaluated is  $$\int \frac{(x-1)}{(x+1) \sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}dx$$

I split the integral to obtain
$$\int \frac{\sqrt x}{(x+1) \sqrt{x^2+x+1}}dx - \int \frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}dx$$

But I could not proceed any further, as I am not able to find any substitution, nor could I find any further simplification.

I tried by multiplying the numerator and denominator with $\sqrt {x-1}$ so as to obtain $ x^3-1$ inside the radical, but that didn't help either.

How should I proceed to evaluate this integral?

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x-1)%2F((x%2B1)*sqrt(x%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx))) suggests that the indefinite integral can be expressed in terms of [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the first and third kind.

Comment: look like WA is not that smart. $2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x+1+x^{-1}}$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice
$$\begin{align}
  \int \frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}dx
= &\int \frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x+1+x^{-1}}}\frac{dx}{x}\\
= &\int \frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x+1+x^{-1}}}\frac{d(x+1+x^{-1})}{x-x^{-1}}\\
= &\int \frac{d(x+1+x^{-1})}{(x+2+x^{-1})\sqrt{x+1+x^{-1}}}
\end{align}
$$
Let $u = \sqrt{x + 1 +x^{-1}}$, the indefinite integral evaluates to
$$\int \frac{du^2}{(1+u^2)u} = 2\int \frac{du}{1+u^2} 
= 2\tan^{-1}(u) + \text{ const.}
= 2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x+1+x^{-1}} + \text{ const.}$$